# Move, rotate and scale text using custom layout in android

Tags: android, rotation, scaletransform

Hi I want to do something like this

[image]

When user presses rotate icon, text contained in box should gradually rotate and using scale icon, text should be resized.

Right now I am using this code for moving the textview everywhere on the screen

```
 private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {


    final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
    final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
            _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
            layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
            layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
            layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            break;
    }
    elementslayout.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

It is working fine. 
On long press of textview I want to show the layout with rotate and scale icon.
 My question is,

```
 How to create this type of layout for textview and do rotate and scale accordingly?
```

I have seen many codes for rotate and scale using matrix like 
http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/

But don't know how to use it here.

Comment: Did you find anything useful for this? If yes, then please post your answer here.

Comment: @n1m1 please post ansewer if you got solution

Answer (score -1):

I also want to do the same thing, Rotate,Scale as well as move textview all together. I found a link for text rotation here.

[Android Two finger rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682019/android-two-finger-rotation)

This works totally fine for the text rotation. You just need to add

```
txt.setRotation(-angle);
```

In the onRotation Method. May be that helps you.