# move, rotation and zoom in\out on View

Tags: android, android-studio, gesture

I'm new to android development and I need to develop view with some specifications

1. **move by touch**
2. **scale by pinch (zoom in\out)**
3. **rotation using two fingures**

I've developed rotation by using these steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682019/android-two-finger-rotation) but there are some issues like jumping view if one finger removed suddenly.

and for move used this code it works well but think it is issue in sudden movement.

```
 public static View.OnTouchListener getTouchListener(){
    View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        int prevX, prevY;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams par = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.bringToFront();
                    prevX = (int) event.getRawX();
                    prevY = (int) event.getRawY();
                    par.bottomMargin = -8 * v.getHeight();
                    par.rightMargin = -8 * v.getWidth();
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    return true;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    par.topMargin += (int) event.getRawY() - prevY;
                    prevY = (int) event.getRawY();
                    par.leftMargin += (int) event.getRawX() - prevX;
                    prevX = (int) event.getRawX();
                    v.setLayoutParams(par);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    return onTouchListener;
}
```

I need someone help me to get the three features together without any issues 
Hint: if there is library it is welcomed.

Comment: Have you checked gitHub? it has lots of libraries probably with this implementation already.

Comment: @Kristofer i checked it but what i find is implemented to work on images only and i need it for a different view if there is one like this, please mention one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After long of searching about how to implement something like that, I finally found a repository on GitHub solving my issue
you can find classes for doing that [here](https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views/tree/master/libraries/collage-views/src/main/java/com/thuytrinh/android/collageviews)

and way to use the classes is:

```
        yourView.setOnTouchListener(new MultiTouchListener());
```

in this way you can scale, zoom in/out (by pinch) and rotate the view by pinch too.

Comment: I'm not able to rotate surface view using this. Please guide me.

Comment: can you create question please and let us see your full code?

Answer (score 1):

the perfect example of what u r searching is here:[see here(example)](http://codesfor.in/move-zoom-and-rotate-imageview-in-android/)

Happy coding!

Comment: thank you but your example is for imageView I needed it on any view.
or you mean I can do the sane to any other view?

Comment: For the newcomers, the above also works for any View, its given in that tutorial

Comment: @Mihir Joshi your link is broken